# How do i get my preg_match to show the first instance?

Tags: preg-match

I have the following code

```
    $atk="[2] Skedaddle (20) Shuffle Aipom and all basic Energy cards attached to it into your deck. (Discard all other cards attached to Aipom.) (If you have no Benched Pokemon, this attack does nothing.)";

    preg_match('#\[(.*)\] (.*) \((.*)\) (.*)#', $atk2, $matchatk2);
    $atkcost = $matchatk2[1];
    $atkname = $matchatk2[2];
    $atkdmg = $matchatk2[3];
    $atktext = $matchatk2[4];
```

It it returning the following:

```
2
Skedaddle (20) Shuffle Aipom and all basic Energy cards attached to it into your deck.
Discard all other cards attached to Aipom.
(If you have no Benched Pokemon, this attack does nothing.)
```

I need it to return:

```
2
Skedaddle 
20 
Shuffle Aipom and all basic Energy cards attached to it into your deck. (Discard all other cards attached to Aipom.)(If you have no Benched Pokemon, this attack does nothing.)
```

I have tried perg_match_all but it returned the same results.

I have looked all over for an answer to my question and could not find an answer that pertained to it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the **non greedy** regex quantifier `?`.

Like this:

```
 $atk="[2] Skedaddle (20) Shuffle Aipom and all basic Energy cards attached to it into your deck. (Discard all other cards attached to Aipom.) (If you have no Benched Pokemon, this attack does nothing.)";

    preg_match('#\[(.*?)\] (.*?) \((.*?)\) (.*)#', $atk, $matchatk2);
    $atkcost = $matchatk2[1];
    $atkname = $matchatk2[2];
    $atkdmg = $matchatk2[3];
    $atktext = $matchatk2[4];
```

DEMO:
http://ideone.com/36DRLa

[Mastering Quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html)

Comment: That's it! Why is the php manual not clear; I read that and thought not what I need.

Comment: I use this software to check my regex syntax and results before using with php. http://www.regexbuddy.com/